# skype alias, redirect or merge?

Tags: skype

A friend got two skype accounts, lets say j.doe and john.doe on different devices. I guess he forgot his password or account name, and just created another.

So when I want to contact him, I usually make a group of his two aliases and write to that.

Is it somehow possible to merge the accounts so he can be contacted under both addreses?

Or can he set up one account to say "I'm not using j.doe anymore, please contact me at john.doe instead"?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to merge the accounts so he can be contacted under both addresses?

No, merging Skype accounts is not possible:

> There is no option to merge/update one Skype account to another Skype
> account.
>
> You can only merge/update your Skype and Microsoft accounts.

Source [Merging two Skype accounts - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/merging-two-skype-accounts/74c02e28-5c6f-4fba-88cf-2565909a12c1)

He can, however, forward calls from one account to the other (provided he still has access to both accounts):

> **How do I use Skype call forwarding?**
>
> Call forwarding lets you forward your Skype calls to voice messaging,
> a landline or mobile number, or another Skype contact. To set up call
> forwarding:
>
> - Sign in to your account.
> - In the Manage Features section, select Call forwarding.
> - Select the button [image: call forwarding disabled] to enable call forwarding [image: call forwarding enabled] and then select how many seconds to
>   forward calls after.
> - Choose voice messaging, **another Skype account (enter the Skype Name)** or a mobile or landline number (select the country or region
>   and enter the phone number).
> - Select Confirm.
>
> Your incoming calls will be forwarded even if you're not signed in to
> Skype.

Source [How do I use Skype call forwarding? | Skype Support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12258/how-do-i-use-skype-call-forwarding)

Comment: Does that include chat messages?

Comment: @Lenne No. [It has never been possible to forward a chat message from one account to another.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/can-i-forward-chat-messages-from-a-skype-account/4add7e0a-f350-4590-8eae-27366a7c39bc)